# SQL Server recursive query - view in hierarchical order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query some information from a maufacturing system.
With the many posts here in this forum I was able to build a recursive query but now I'm stuck with finishing it.

I have a table that shows an assembly that needs to be manufactured and all sub-assemblies and components.

Simplified it looks like this:

| assembly | component | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| machine_a | front_cover | 1 |
| machine_a | side_cover | 2 |
| front_cover | screw | 4 |
| front_cover | sheet_metal_a | 1 |
| side_cover | screw | 4 |
| side_cover | sheet_metal_b | 1 |
| machine_b | box | 1 |
| box | screw | 8 |
| box | sheet_metal | 1 |

Now I'm interested in machine_a and all its components / sub assemblies. This machine consist of one time the front_cover and two times the side_cover and some screws.

To list all components for a specific machine I'm running a recursive query:

```
declare @assembly nchar(20) = 'machine_a';

WITH whole_machine AS (
    SELECT       
        assembly_parent, 
        component,
        amount,
        0 as Level,
        amount as total
   FROM       
        manufacturing
    WHERE assembly_parent=@assembly
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        man.assembly_parent, 
        man.component,
        man.amount,
        Level + 1,
        man.amount * mach.total as total
    FROM 
        manufacturing man
        INNER JOIN whole_machine mach
        ON mach.component = man.assembly_parent
)

select * from whole_machine;
```

That works as expected and I'm getting "machine_a" with all its components and the correct level:

| assembly_parent | component | amount | Level | total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| machine_a | front_cover | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| machine_a | side_cover | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| side_cover | screw | 4 | 1 | 8 |
| side_cover | sheet_metal_b | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| front_cover | screw | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| front_cover | sheet_metal_a | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Is there a way to have that list sorted by hierarchy? So instead of having listed anything with Level 0 first, then Level 1, then Level 2, etc. to rather show it in the order the components belong together? Kind of like this:

```
machine_a
    front_cover
        screw
        sheet_metal_a
    side_cover
        screw
        sheet_metal_b
```

That means it's the list above but it should show in this order:

| assembly_parent | component | amount | Level | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| machine_a | front_cover | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| front_cover | screw | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| front_cover | sheet_metal_a | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| machine_a | side_cover | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| side_cover | screw | 4 | 1 | 8 |
| side_cover | sheet_metal_b | 1 | 1 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. You need a lineage for all of the parts. If each of the rows in your table has an ID, you can construct such a lineage with the CTE that you're already using.

```sql
declare @assembly nchar(20) = 'machine_a';

with manufacturing as (
    select * from (values
        (1, 'machine_a', 'front_cover', 1),
        (2, 'machine_a', 'side_cover', 2),
        (3, 'front_cover', 'screw', 4),
        (4, 'front_cover', 'sheet_metal_a', 1),
        (5, 'side_cover', 'screw', 4),
        (6, 'side_cover', 'sheet_metal_b', 1),
        (7, 'machine_b', 'box', 1),
        (8, 'box', 'screw', 8),
        (9, 'box', 'sheet_metal', 1)
    ) as x(id, assembly_parent, component, amount)
)
, whole_machine AS (
    SELECT       
        assembly_parent, 
        component,
        amount,
        amount as total,

        0 as Level,
        h = cast( concat('/', id, '/') as varchar(max))
   FROM       
        manufacturing
    WHERE assembly_parent=@assembly
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        man.assembly_parent, 
        man.component,
        man.amount,
        man.amount * mach.total,

        Level + 1,
        h = cast( concat(mach.h, man.id, '/' ) as varchar(max))
    FROM 
        manufacturing man
        INNER JOIN whole_machine mach
        ON mach.component = man.assembly_parent
)

select *
from whole_machine
order by h;
```

Note, h can be converted to a hierarchyid (which I'm a big fan of). It has the advantage of being able to be persisted into a table alongside your data so instead of needing to construct the lineage at query time, it can be done at data mutation time. I can write that up if that's something you're interested in exploring.

Comment: I don't have an ID column as single number and I can't add extra columns or tables in the database (for manufacturer support reasons). My table has multiple PKs.

So instead of `h = cast( concat('/', id, '/') as varchar(max))` i used something like `h = cast( concat('/', pk_col_x,px_col_y,pk_col_z, '/') as varchar(max))`
That worked well. Many thanks!

Comment: Sure. I used an ID because it was convenient; a multi-column PK should work just as well. In that case though (for anyone reading this in the future), the comment about being able to use this approach to construct a hierarchyid is called into question (i.e. may or may not work depending on what the datatypes of the constituent columns are).